# Issue on enable XSL extension in WHM VPS

Tags: xslt, command-line, ssh, cpanel, vps

I want to install [rtwi](http://rtwi.jmk.hu/) that require to enable XSL extension in VPS.
I use WHM and i enable that in my `WHM > Software > Apache Update > Exhaustive Options List`
But when run script get this error: `Fatal error: Class 'XSLTprocessor' not found` that show XSL extension disable. 
I test any solution in web for this and use many different SSH code in command line but i can`t fix this issue.

Please tel me what must i do

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile PHP with XSL installed. To do this run EasyApache from WHM and choose "XSL" from "PHP 5.x" options in the Exhaustive Options List.

You can also run /scripts/easyapache from SSH and follow the process above.